# Volume of $2$ Solids of Revolution

Tags: integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

The region bounded by $ x = y^{2}$ and $x = 2-y^{2}$, revolved around the line $x = 3$.

By using the Washer method, I acquire:
$$\pi \int_{-1}^{1} (y^2)^2 - (1-y^2)^2 \space dy$$

However after integration, the final result does not match those of an online calculator. I'm just wondering where I went wrong with the equation. The concept of revolution is a bit confusing to me, especially in this question where the functions are symmetrical to each other, and I'm not sure which is the top/bottom or right/left function.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:$V = \pi\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \left((3-y^2)^2-(3-(2-y^2))^2\right)dy=\pi\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \left((9-6y^2+y^4)-(1+2y^2+y^4)\right) =\pi\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \left(8-8y^2\right)dy=16\pi\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} (1-y^2)dy=\dfrac{32\pi}{3}.$.

Comment: Okay, I get the latter part of the integral, but may I ask why it is (3-y^2)^2?  Won't the radius just be y^2?

Comment: That's the outer radius measured from the center at $x = 3$. It's the distance between two points on the $x$ axis from $y^2$ to $3$. Here $y^2 = x$. In your post, you somehow didn't take into consideration of $x = 3$ and it's the line you rotate the region about.

Comment: Can you see the diagram on the edit that I made? Isn't the distance from the center x = 3 to y^2 just x since y^2 lies on y = 0? Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, it's $3-x = 3 -y^2$. You are still counting from the $y$ axis. It should be counted from the line $x = 3$. Your answer is correct if you rotate the region about the $y$ axis. But you indicated in your post that the region is rotated about the line $x = 3$. So it changes the radii.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it helps you see the difference when the axis of rotation moves to another location from the traditional $y$ axis.

Comment: Won't this mean that the volume would differ if it was rotated around the traditional y-axis, since the distance from the point of rotation to the function is just x itself?

Comment: Yes, it would and I've mentioned it in my other comments.

Comment: Okay, just making sure I understand the concept. Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: Sure. Any time.

Answer (score 0):

***Not an answer*** but a reference for understanding.

$$
\text { Volume of revolution}=\int_{-1}^{1} \pi\left(3-2+y^{2}\right)^{2} d y-\int_{-1}^{1} \pi\left(3-y^{2}\right)^{2} d y
$$

[image]